# Abstract Idea Definition

Tags: patents

35 U. S. C. §101 highlights "laws of nature, natural phenomena, and abstract ideas" as patent-ineligible.

The Alice/Bank case discusses abstract ideas and explains that in applying the §101 exception, a court must distinguish patents that claim the “building blocks” of human ingenuity. Where are the rules written on applying the §101 exceptions?

For a precise definition of what the exceptions are, do I need to review the relevant cases or are they defined somewhere?

Comment: Perfect, thanks. If you want to throw that down as an answer rather than comment, I'll give it the tick and can close.

Comment: Whatever you think would be most beneficial for the reader. I have posted an answer that gets straight to the point on the definition of an abstract idea which is what I was looking for. Whilst the other question includes the relevant link, the wording of this one makes it a prequel rather than I duplicate, I'd say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Abstract ideas have been identified by the courts by way of example, including  fundamental economic practices, certain methods of organizing human activities,
an idea ‘of itself,’ and mathematical relationships/formulas.

They are the building blocks of human ingenuity.

Full guidance [here](http://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/FR-2014-12-16/pdf/2014-29414.pdf). This should be read in conjunction with the relevant cases it references to understand the notion of abstract ideas in intellectual property law.

Follow on question [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/452/how-much-more-needs-to-be-added-to-an-abstract-idea-in-order-to-pass-the-subje/568#568)